# Alexa skill not returning anything in Alexa simulator

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have a very simple Alexa skill.  It has one intent, that one intent calls a function in AWS lambda and returns a response correctly.  When I I test in the lambda console everything works as expected, when I send JSON directly from the Alexa developer console everything works as expected, but when I use the Alexa simulator I don't get anything for a response.

JSON input and output are both blank, and the debugging info I get looks like pseudocode:

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "SkillDebugger",
        "name": "CaptureDebuggingInfo",
        "messageId": "caa2b8e4-d26b-4946-9063-b72b4261b50b"
    },
    "payload": {
        "skillId": null,
        "timestamp": "2019-06-14T14:15:13.140Z",
        "dialogRequestId": "bfb2ff84-59b8-4bc4-9826-85453fc7c290",
        "skillRequestId": null,
        "type": "ConsideredIntents",
        "content": {
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "<IntentForDifferentSkill>",
                    "confirmationStatus": null,
                    "slots": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "<IntentForDifferentSkill>",
                    "confirmationStatus": null,
                    "slots": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "<IntentForDifferentSkill>",
                    "confirmationStatus": null,
                    "slots": null
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you start with your invocation phrase?

e.g. for the python hello world sample skill, you would test with the following dialogue:

```html
<pre>
$ask dialog --locale en-US
  User  >  open greeter
  Alexa >  Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say hello!
  User  >  hi!
  Alexa >  Hello Python World from Decorators!
---------- Skill Session Ended ----------
  User  >
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the language used in the Alexa simulator matches the language set for the Interaction Model.

For example, you're simulator might be using `English (UK)` while the Interaction Model set to `English (US)`. If this is the case, easiest solution is to toggle the Alexa simulator language to match that used in the Interaction Model.

This would also explain why it works as expected both through the AWS lambda function and for when sending a manual JSON request from the Alexa developer console - they don't rely on the language set.